# ng-bootstrap alerts won't close

Tags: ng-bootstrap

My alerts won't close when I click the X button.

I've used angular cli to create a new app.  I followed the instructions [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers) to load bootstrap:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

Then I followed instructions [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) to load ng-bootstrap:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Testing...';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<ngb-alert>Alert</ngb-alert>
...
```

The alert shows up, and is styled properly, but it doesn't close when I click the X.  Other components are working (tabset, dropdown).  Am I missing something in app.component.ts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to define a `close` event method in your component.

### HTML:

```
<ngb-alert *ngIf="!closed" (close)="closed=true">Alert</ngb-alert>
```

### Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Testing...';
  closed = false;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Simple and great answer respect , define variable to show and hide alert based on the demands

Answer (score 1):

This is very late but might help others looking for a simple closeable alert.  This component wraps Devansh's solution:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-alert',
    template: '<ngb-alert [type]="type" *ngIf="open" (close)="open=false"><ng-content></ng-content></ngb-alert>',
})
export class InfoPanelComponent {
    public open = true;
    @Input() type = 'info';
}
```

usage:

```
<app-alert>I'm a closeable alert!</app-alert>
```